# Abbreviated relative time (Instagram style) using momentjs language wise dynamic?

Tags: momentjs

```
moment().startOf('day').fromNow() //3 days ago.
```

How can I change the above to show 3d instead of language is English and to
 "3 j" if language is french and so on dynamically change according to the language?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `moment.locale` method as reported in the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/). Remember that you have to import all locales you need or you can use `moment-with-locales.js` that provides all supported locales.

**EDIT:**

To customize format of momentjs `fromNow` method you can use `updateLocale` as documented in the Customize -> [Relative time](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/) section of the docs.

```js
moment.updateLocale('en',{
    relativeTime : {
        future: "in %s",
        past:   "%s",
        s:  "seconds",
        m:  "a minute",
        mm: "%d minutes",
        h:  "an hour",
        hh: "%d h",
        d:  "a day",
        dd: "%d d",
        M:  "a month",
        MM: "%d months",
        y:  "a year",
        yy: "%d years"
    }
});

moment.updateLocale('fr',{
    relativeTime : {
        future : 'dans %s',
        past : '%s',
        s : 'quelques secondes',
        m : 'une minute',
        mm : '%d minutes',
        h : 'une heure',
        hh : '%d heures',
        d : 'un jour',
        dd : '%d j',
        M : 'un mois',
        MM : '%d mois',
        y : 'un an',
        yy : '%d ans'
    }
});

moment.locale('fr');
moment().subtract(2, 'days').startOf('day').fromNow() // 2 j
moment.locale('en');
moment().subtract(2, 'days').startOf('day').fromNow() // 2 d
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is giving complete string like // 9 hours ago , i want to show in mobile device where i need abbreviated form dynamically according to language. Like we have in instagram. https://www.instagram.com/p/BF6kEjfJyLg/?hl=fr                      for english https://www.instagram.com/p/BF6kEjfJyLg/?hl=en Look at the time passed. Pls help

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its helpful, But , do i need to customize for every language similarly ? Let's say we have 25 languages so i need to make modifications for all the languages , Is it fine ?